# How to cut chevron detail on mjolnir handle

Tags: router, turning, carving

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to the handle on this:

[image: Replica thor hammer blueprint]

I want to do this entirely in wood. How would I go about cutting that on a wood lathe? Or any way for that matter...

Comment: I think Thor would expect you to carve this by hand.

Comment: I deleted my previous Comment because I looked for large enough images of the original MCU mjolnir and they showed clearly that the handle is not spirally wound. I was thrown by previous knowledge that such wire on real weapon handles *is* a wind (which is probably the only application that really makes sense, but whatever, it's the movies)! Anyway, not sure if you can see this at your user score but your Q has gotten two close votes for being off-topic. Can you confirm that you're not looking to do this in metal as the blueprints specify but *are* seeking to recreate this in wood? [contd]

Comment: If you are, please edit the Question to reflect this and whether you see these details as being incised into the wood (as I think you're currently thinking) or being a raised detail (which is is on the movie prop). Either way *this is not something you'd do on the lathe*. BTW I was also very confused initially by the router tag, since I'm not sure how you'd use a router to do anything to a workpiece mounted on a lathe O_O

Comment: You'd cut something using a router on a lathe like so: https://www.instructables.com/Router-Fluting-Jig-for-Wood-Lathe/ using a fluting jig of some type. I do belive I'm going to end up cutting these using a palm router a bushing and a 3d printed circular template using the indexing feature on the lathe :)

Comment: I AM seeking to recreate this in wood completly yes :)

Comment: I've edited the Q and withdrawn my close vote accordingly. Coincidentally one of the Marvel films was on last night and I watched it today. Very briefly near the end of the film there's a very close view of one side of mjolnir's handle and I don't think this can be created by routing, at least not in the way you're envisaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might most easily be created by hand carving, as least for most of the careful shaping work.

If you want to create a good facsimile of the MCU mjolnir, close examination of the hero prop in one or more of the films, along with any good licensed collector pieces, would be advisable, rather than going by the 'blueprint' which has a host of failings<sup>1</sup>.

Although the following collector piece is a bit cheesy I think it represents the chevrons fairly accurately and it highlights that the 'blueprint' is highly flawed here:

[image: licensed(?) collector mjolnir]

Because this is not a spiral feature (a winding) and instead individual metal pieces with lateral symmetry<sup>2</sup> I don't believe it's possible to cut this detail simply using a router and rotating the handle, either under power or carefully by hand.

Also note that in the original these are not an incised detail, they are a *raised* detail.

How exactly you choose to represent this in wood is of course up to you, but simply carving or routing a single groove per chevron seems to me to produce the least satisfying representation (while still being a perfectly reasonable way to add grip to an otherwise smooth shaft it must be said).

Personally, at the least I would incise two small, shallow parallel grooves either side of each chevron. But the most faithful recreation is for these features to end up raised, which obviously entails removing all of the wood around them.

This is a lot of work by hand, but I think some setup using a horizontally mounted router could be created to do the bulk of this removal, moving the handle by hand with the router fixed in place.

**Safety note**
Even if a very small round-nosed or core-box bit is fitted to the router, and even with very shallow projection it's still **extremely** dangerous to have an exposed router bit sticking out unguarded while it's under power, so the utmost caution must be exercised if you cannot fit some kind of guard.

A guard of acrylic or polycarbonate would be easy to create and fit to such a routing jig and I highly advise doing this.

Without such a guard in place personally I would make the handle very much over-length (double?) so that I could manipulate the workpiece with my bare hands<sup>3</sup> while keeping my fingers safely inches away (10cm +) from the bit while nibbling away the excess material.

Final shaping would be done by hand, using as much rasping/filing/scraping and/or sanding as you feel necessary to create a smooth transition and surface finish you're happy with.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not the worst of which is the poor representation of the handle details you're asking about!

<sup>2</sup> Not simple circumferential features, i.e. not ovals.

<sup>3</sup> Gloves and rotating power tools being generally considered an absolute no-no, because of the danger of the material being snagged and actually dragging you into the spinning workpiece or tool.

Answer (score 2):

According to the diagram you have:

- Metal ridge - in another section of the "blueprint" this is labeled as "unbreakable leather". You could go with a ridge in the wood or just leather wrap.
- Knurled pattern

[image]

The "blueprints" indicate both a raised ridge and a leather wrap that looks like it spirals down the handle and between the raised ridge is knurling.

If you go with a raised ridge it looks similar to turning a a thread with (as an example) one thread per 2 inch. Like this only with threads very spread out, less thread height and rounded rather than pointed:
[image]

If you went with the ridges as individual rings rather than a spiral it would be easier.

And if you go with the leather wrap it would be even easier to make, just wrap the leather over the knurl.

Here is a picture of knurled wood:
[image]
Check youtube for videos on wood knurling

Comment: Like a lot of fan-sourced plans and what purport to be blueprints this is all about looking convincing and not actually about being a proper plan, so this isn't as clear as it could be. But you've mis-read what it says, it's not a metal ridge *and* knurling, it's a "metal ridge (knurled pattern)" i.e. a knurled metal ridge (over the leather handle wrap).

Comment: @Graphus I don't think you would knurl metal and put it over the leather handle wrap. You are right, I missed the instruction to use "unbreakable leather " to wrap the handle. If the spiral ridge is a leather wrap it would be easier to make. Either way, and even with the fanciful blueprint, replicating Thor's hammer in wood is an interesting project. I have edited the answer to cover both possibilities.

Comment: You aren't wrong that it kind of looks like a spiral in this diagram but I'm looking at images of what appears to be the hero prop from the films and they are chevrons by the looks of things... E. G https://images.app.goo.gl/T85zchXopKbTXyxf9

Comment: @vimes1984 Thanks for the pictures - it was amazing how many different styles of handle there are!

Comment: yeah, there are a tonne of different types I'm currently delving into the prop forums: https://www.therpf.com/forums/threads/accurate-mcu-mjolnir-dimensions.338709/page-3 trying to get dimensions... it's a whole world I had NO IDEA existed... anyway I still don't know how to cut these chevrons...

Comment: @vimes1984, *"anyway I still don't know how to cut these chevrons"* if you still don't know how to cut/carve these then you shouldn't have selected an Answer yet (sorry David).